# Sphider for searching keywords in PDF

Tags: php, pdf, search, sphider

Can Sphider be customized for searching keywords in PDF?

I know that Sphider is written in PHP.

Comment: You may want to elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish.  Have you already started development using sphider, or would you be open to other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From sphider's [doc](http://www.sphider.eu/docs.php#pdfdoc):

> Indexing pdf and doc files
>
> Pdf and doc files can be indexed via
>   external binaries. Download and install pdftotext and catdoc and set
>   there location(path) in conf.php (note that under Windows, you should
>   not use spaces in defining the executable's path). Additionally, in
>   admin section, check the Index pdf and Index doc boxes (alternatively,
>   set $index_pdf and $index_doc parameters to 1 in conf.php).